# How to hide webform label from email only?

Tags: 7, theming, webforms, emails

I'm currently using the Webform module to build a warranty support form for Drupal 7.

Here is a screen shot of the webform:

[image: Screenshot of Warranty Support Webform]

Below is the email output I receive when the form is submitted:

> James Blunte.g. Joe Smith (jamesblunt@123.com) has submitted a warranty request.
>
> Order Number: 39840e.g. 1248

I've used the right label to show examples of what to enter in the field on the webform. My question is how do I hide the label from showing on the email template? As you can see the label follows right after the value.

Here is a screenshot of my 'Edit Components' page:
[image: Edit Component Page]

I can see how it's useful for the label to appear, but in my case I don't need it in the email.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take quite a bit to edit the email templates. The truth is that this is design behavior, because labels

The better way to do what you want is to put that text in the help/description field of the component and then style it with CSS. That text is not included in the email.

Comment: Genius!! I completely let that one fly over my head. Thanks for the help.